# When will GetType() return RunTimeType and when will it return the a Type like SampleProgram.MyClass1?

Tags: c#, .net

I am learning about reflection and the `GetType()` method.

I notice that when I define types within an application and call the `GetType()` method it returns the `type(class)` of the object.

```
Class1 first = new Class1();
Class2 second = new Class2();
Type firstType = first.GetType();
Type secondType = second.GetType();
Console.WriteLine(firstType.ToString());//prints Class1
Console.WriteLine(secondType.ToString());//prints Class2
```

At the same time when I load another assembly using `Assembly.LoadFrom()` and iterate over the types using a `foreach`, the `GetType()` returns `RunTimeType`.

```
foreach (Type t in AddInAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (t.IsClass && typeof(IAddIn).IsAssignableFrom(t))
    {
        AddInTypes.Add(t);
        Console.WriteLine(t.GetType());//prints RunTimeType
    }
}
```

What is happening? Is My understanding wrong? Can anyone throw light on this behaviour.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe it will make more sense in this example:

```
Class1 someObj = new Class1();
Type type1 = someObj.GetType(); // Class1
Type type2 = type1.GetType(); // RuntimeType
```

In your first example, you're working with objects of type `Class1` and `Class2`, so when you use `GetType()` it returns the `Type`s representing `Class1` and `Class2`.

In your second example, you're working with objects of type `Type`, which represent `Class1` and `Class2`. When you use `GetType()` on these, it returns `RuntimeType` (which extends `Type`).

As further explanation, here are the types and contents of each variable after running my above example:

```
Variable | Type        | Content
someObj  | Class1      | N/A
type1    | RuntimeType | Class1
type2    | RuntimeType | RuntimeType
```

Answer (score 8):

`GetType()` returns the type of the instance you call it on.

`t` is a `Type` instance, so it returns the subclass of `System.Type` that `t` actually is (usually `RuntimeType`).

That's exactly like writing `"4".GetType().GetType()`.

Answer (score 3):

[`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as specified in the documentation returns:

> The exact runtime type of the current instance.

In your case, the variable `t` is declared as `Type t`. `GetType` for an instance of type `Type` will not return `Type` though, [because](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Type is an abstract base class that allows multiple implementations. The system will always provide the derived class RuntimeType. In reflection, all classes beginning with the word Runtime are created only once per object in the system and support comparison operations.

In your example however, if you would change your troubleshooting call to this:

```
Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
```

you would get the result you expect.